# How to HMAC a function in Python?

Tags: cryptography, hmac, can-bus

HMAC can be applied for strings using the following code

```
import hmac
import hashlib
digest_maker=hmac.new(b'secret key',b'apple',hashlib.sha1)
digest=digest_maker.hexdigest()
print(digest)
```

But I want to implement HMAC for something like this

```
f=dev.recv()
```

here dev.recv() will be continuously receiving CAN message which will be stored in f. The values stored in f has to to be HMACed

I have implemented Hash for the same scenario. I want to implement HMAC for the same scenario

```
from canard import can
from canard.hw import socketcan
import hashlib
dev=socketcan.SocketCanDev("slcan0")
dev.start()
while True:
  f=dev.recv()
  hash_object = hashlib.sha256(str(f).encode('utf-8'))
  print('Hash', hash_object.hexdigest())
```

I have attached the output of Hash
[image]

Comment: It probably took more time to for you to post this than to figure it out yourself by reading documentation and simply trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your apple with `str(f).encode('utf-8')`.

Use a real random key instead of a password and preferably something different than SHA-1 (it's still secure for HMAC, but attacks only get better).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the hmac object as a continuously updating thing:

```
h=hmac.new(b'secret key',None, hashlib.sha256)
while True:
    f=dev.recv()
    h.update(f)
```

and and the end (after you have all the data) you can see the result with `h.digest()` (raw) or `h.hexdigest()` (hexified string) and compare the expected result with the actual one, e.g. You can call it at every block too, as you do in the example.

The hash object you use in your example refreshes for every received block, and has no secret information (so can easily be spoofed).

Comment: How can it be prevented from spoofing?

Comment: @annonymous only if you know the secret key, one can compute the correct HMAC digest.

Comment: @annonymous E.g. see [this answer on cryptography stack exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/5647/553)